# How to use a custom Project Template in Middleman on Windows

Tags: ruby, middleman

I have created a custom project template for Middleman. The [documentation](http://middlemanapp.com/guides/getting-started/) states that I should store templates in the `~/.middleman/` folder. This works fine on Mac, but where should I store the template on Windows 7?

I have tried putting it in a `.middleman` folder in the `%UserProfile%` directory. But when I run `middleman init --help`, the custom template is not displayed in the list of available templates.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. The home path was not what I expected. I ran puts File.expand_path("~/") in Ruby to find out where Middleman expects the .middleman directory to be located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. The home path was not what I expected. I ran `puts File.expand_path("~/")` in Ruby to find out where Middleman expects the `.middleman` directory to be located.

Comment: How did you do this exactly? I'm trying to create my own custom templates for regular freelance work I do but can't seem to figure out where to put the templates on my windows machine. I'm using the Rails installer if that makes a difference

Comment: Hey Tom, I saved `puts File.expand_path("~/")` into a file called test.rb, and then I ran `ruby test.rb` from the command line. This prints out the full path to the folder where you should create a .middleman directory.